# "Consequently" versus "consequentially"

Tags: differences, adverbs

What is the difference between *consequent**ly*** and *consequent**ially***?

My usage being what it is, and also *according to the dictionary sample sentences I've found so far* (thank you for the helpful comment @Thomas), I think they can be used interchangeably, usually intended to mean "As a consequence [of some action described in the preceding sentence], ...".

Comment: What do dictionaries say?

Comment: The dictionary says they're the same thing, only different.  Seriously -- look it up -- about the only clear difference I can find is that the '...ially' form is said to be rare.  I'm interested to know about correct usage -- because the 'rare' claim doesn't hold true, at least for my environemnt -- folks use it all the time.

Comment: oic. Well if the people around you normally say it, you could just ignore the advice in my answer about avoiding it. You could try pointing out that it's not exactly the standard form for many others, but since it is at least "technically valid", people might not thank you for criticising the way they speak!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- true enough!  I won't criticize the way anyone speaks. (I need to be about 6 inches taller before I can think about getting away with that sort of thing.)  But I appreciate your answer -- the 'indirect result' implication was something new.

Comment: If you need help remembering it, just think about the related/opposite word "inconsequential" (which will also remind you about the "importance" meaning).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have to say first that *consequentially* is a pretty rare word. My advice would be to steer well clear of it, because nearly every time you use it, people will assume you're making a mistake and that you should have used *consequently*.

In principle *consequentially* does overlap in meaning with *consequently*, in that they can both mean *as a result [of whatever has just been mentioned]*, but *consequentially* has more the implication of an *indirect result*.

Also note the usage *A man of consequence*, meaning an important man. In my experience, this meaning is never implied by *consequent* or *consequently*, but it often is by  *consequential* (and presumably *consequentially*, but I must be honest and say I myself am not very familiar with that form at all).

It may be helpful to consider the common negated form [inconsequential](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/inconsequential) (normally meaning *trivial, having no significant consequences*, but sometimes also applied to things that do not logically follow from what's just been said).

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers -- that's kind of what I thought -- I'd found one reference that said that the adjective form could connote important, or alternatively pompous or self-important.  As for the adverb form, I just can't find any clear difference other than one is said to be rarely used.

Comment: @kuru kuru na... [Here's](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=consequentially%2Cconsequently&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) an NGram showing usage for the longer form virtually 'flatlines' against the standard one. But the *indirect result* is definitely a significant semantic difference, and that's the meaning you'll often find if you browse some of the written occurences.