# What are some synonyms of "as a consequence"?

Tags: phrases, synonyms, adverbial-phrases

What are some other phrases/words with similar meanings to "as a consequence"?

For example,

> Temperature is increasing. As a consequence, the number of cyclones is
> increasing due to [.......]

I would like to start another sentence just after the above sentences with exactly the same meaning as  "as a consequence", e.g.,

> As a consequence, the damages to the societal values is increasing.

Comment: 'Therefore', 'Ergo', 'This means that', 'It can be seen that', 'Consequentially'...

Comment: "another result" perhaps ?

Comment: Perhaps all you mean is *furthermore*.  Also, in the original, you have 'consequence' and 'due to,' which may be repetitious.  If the cyclones are are 'a consequence' of heat, then the sentence already said they're 'due to' heat.

Comment: @YosefBaskin.. I have used the "due to" to give a reason. For instance, as a consequence, number of cyclones are increasing due to the creation of more low pressure systems over the Ocean. Would you please suggest, is it misleading?

Comment: Two ideas: As a consequence, **the** number of cyclones are increasing from the creation of more low pressure systems over the ocean. The number of cyclones are increasing with the rising temperatures, due to the creation of more low pressure systems over the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent phrases include: ". . . hence",". . . as a result", and " . . . for that reason" (in addition to marcellothearcane's suggestions). I would use "consequently" instead of "consequentially," which is rare (and, I believe, a modern variant). See ["Consequently" versus "consequentially"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35732/consequently-versus-consequentially).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***therefore***:

> ***[therefore](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/therefore)***
>
> ADVERB
>
> For that reason; consequently.
>   *‘he was injured and therefore unable to play’*

or any number of [its synonyms](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/therefore).